# Two layers of NGINX reverse proxies with ssl_client_verify on the second

Tags: nginx, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

The project I'm working on is an application that is deployed onto a Kubernetes cluster and uses a smartcard PKI scheme for authentication. This cluster is shared between several applications and not all of these applications need (or even should have) the client cert verification for PKI. So we are using the [ingress-nginx](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx) helm chart to handle ingress into the cluster, then directing to a second reverse proxy that proxies to the application services (web app, api server, etc.). Both proxies have SSL certificates.

Initially, we were using Ingress annotations and mounting the CA certificates into the ingress-nginx deployment in order to handle the client certificate verification, but now we are trying to handle all of the certificate verification on the second proxy so that we have more control over it. Ingress-nginx is a great tool, but it abstracts away a lot of the server config.

Currently, the problem I'm seeing is that the first proxy (ingress-nginx) is receiving the requests and correctly proxying them on to the second proxy. However, because ingress-nginx doesn't have the `ssl_client_verify` directive, it doesn't request the client's certificate. When the request reaches the second proxy (which does have `ssl_client_verify`), this proxy simply returns a 400 and says that the client never sent a certificate (which it didn't).

How can I tell the second proxy to request the certificate from the first in such a way that the first then requests the certificate from the user? Or if there is a simpler solution, I'm open to that as well.

Our ingress object for the ingress-nginx controller looks like this: (the hostname is populated with kustomize)

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: proxy
  namespace: web
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/issuer: cert-issuer
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - placeholder.com
    secretName: web-cert
  rules:
  - host: placeholder.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: proxy
          servicePort: 443
        path: /
```

and the server configuration I'm using for the second proxy looks like this: (environment variables are substituted on container start for the proxy image)

```
# nginx.conf
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile on;

    keepalive_timeout 65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;
}
```

```
# default.conf
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name ${PROXY_DOMAIN} www.${PROXY_DOMAIN};

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/key.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_verify_depth 4;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/DoDRoots.crt;

    # Inform the proxyed app which user had connected to this TLS endpoint
    add_header X-Client-Verified $ssl_client_verify;
    add_header X-CLient-Certificate $ssl_client_escaped_cert;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/shared_locations.conf;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ${PROXY_DOMAIN} www.${PROXY_DOMAIN};
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

```
# shared_locations.conf
location / {
    proxy_pass http://${DOMAIN_FRONT}:${PORT_FRONT}/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://${DOMAIN_BACK}:${PORT_BACK}/api/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I tell the second proxy to request the certificate from the first in such a way that the first then requests the certificate from the user?

This is not possible. There is no way to terminate the TLS connection at the first proxy while at the same time passing through the client certificate at the TLS level. Apart from that the TLS handshake on the first proxy is finished before the TLS handshake with the second proxy is even started, e.g. there is no way to let the second proxy signal the requirement of a client certificate.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your response. I feared that might be the case. In this circumstance, I am going to abandon the second proxy and just set up a more complex configuration on the ingress controller.